# Use string as object name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Is it possible to access the property of a javascript object using a string?

example: I have a javascript object "obj" that contains a property 'index'.

```
obj.index = 4;
```

Now let's say I have a string whose value is the same as a property name of my object:

```
var str = "index";
```

Can I use the value of the *str* variable to access the 'index' property of 'obj'?

Comment: use the square bracket notation obj[str]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code:

```
obj[str]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array Notation (squire bracket notation )

```
obj[str]
```